# Does R shiny allow to parse an XML file?

Tags: r, xml, parsing, shiny

I parse an uploaded XML file in the *renderPlot* function of the *server.R* script of R-Shiny

```
output$oscar <- renderPlot({
doc <- xmlParse("www/Human_body_front_and_side.svg.eps.xml")

#load the XML as a picture
body<-readPicture(saveXML(doc))

#plot it
grid.arrange(pictureGrob(body), ncol=1)
})
```

but I get the following error for the parsing:

> ```
> XML content does not seem to be XML
> ```

I had loaded the correct libraries (`shiny`, `XML`), and checked that the uploaded xml file is fine.

The interesting point is that if, before starting the "runApp" of R-Shiny, I do in the R terminal:

```
doc <<- xmlParse("Human_body_front_and_side.svg.eps.xml")
```

no error and everything works fine. So it looks like R shiny has an issue with parsing xml. I am a newbie in R-Shiny, hence does anyone see what it needs to recognize that XML file?

Comment: The file is just not in the right folder

Comment: if my R-shiny app is called "test", I saved that xml file in "test/www" and call it with doc <- xmlParse("test/www/file.svg.eps.xml"), is'nt correct?

Comment: remove app folder (test) from the path

Comment: If I call it with  
doc <- xmlParse("www/file.svg.eps.xml") 
I get 
Warning: Error in xpathApply: object 'doc' not found

Comment: This means the file is in the right folder, but it is not well formatted

Comment: ok, but if the file is not well formatted, why can I run successfully xmlParse directly in the R terminal?

Comment: That's a good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)


    shinyUI(fluidPage(

      titlePanel("Human body"),


      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(

        ),
        mainPanel(
          plotOutput("humanBody")
        )
      )
    ))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
    library(XML)
    library(grImport)
    library(gridExtra)
    # Define server logic to draw a histogram
    shinyServer(function(input, output){
      output$humanBody <- renderPlot({
              doc <- readPicture("./www/Human_body_front_and_side.svg.eps.xml")

        grid.arrange(pictureGrob(doc), ncol=1)
      })
    })
```

If the goal is to plot the human body from the xml, this code works. Parsing the xml is not necessary since since the readPicture() function expects an XML which your file already is. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: thanks for your help. You can find the xml file there
 http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=30122562046327270600

Comment: I added some details of the server.R of my question. I tried my code with books.xml but got "argument is of length zero" at the step body<-readPicture(saveXML(doc))

Comment: Which package are you using that provides the readPicture() function?

Comment: The package is grImport, designed to plot postscript images https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grImport/index.html

Comment: Wonderful, in fact I use later the function "xpathSApply" and "xmlAttrs" of the grImport to change the colors of some parts of the human body. It works as a charm. Thanks Valter!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @ValterBeaković, can you please suggest me a solution for this query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71369199/how-to-locate-parse-information-from-a-child-node-and-fill-in-a-value-at-a-dif ?